# Отключение регистрации в gem devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пишу админку для сайта, нужно дать возможность регистрации нового аккаунта только после входа в уже существующий аккаунт. Была мысль полностью отключить регистрацию:

**routing**

```
devise_for :users , :skip => :registerable
```

**model**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :validatable
```

Но это немного не то, подскажите что нибудь. Думал прописать `before_filter :authenticate_admin!` в Devise-контроллере, но не знаю где он находится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регистрация Devise достаточно сильно заточена под **типичный случай**: регистрацию будучи **не** в системе, по общедоступной ссылке с формы входа или из другого места.

В сущности то, чего вы хотите, это типичный `create` для пользователей. Валидации от Devise в модели уже есть и они будут работать из любого (даже вашего) контроллера, реализовывать их ещё раз не надо.

Вам будет проще сделать отдельный контроллер с типичными рельсовыми `new` и `create` и **одну** вьюху с формой на них. И перекрыть доступ в весь контроллер всем, кроме админов. Контроллеры Devise для этого не нужны.

А в этом же контроллере потом можно разместить и оставшиеся средства администрирования пользователей, вроде списка (`index`) и редактирования (`edit`/`update`).

Comment: я сделал как вы сказали, но как сделать так чтоб rails понимал что это именно `create` и `new` для создания devise пользователей (admin) через мой контроллер. Также нашел путь для блокировки регистрации через `if admin_signed_in?` в registrations/new.html.erb
Вот мой `routes`: 
`get '/admin/sign_up' => 'admins#new'`
`devise_for :admin``root 'accounts#index'`
  `resources :accounts`
`resources :images`
  `get '/admin' => 'admins#index', as: 'admin_root'`

Comment: @Escobar а зачем Rails это понимать? Просто употребите ссылки на формы этого контроллера где это уместно и отключите все регистрационные фишки Devise.

Comment: @Escobar я к тому, что вам потребуется только ваша модель `User`. Просто сделайте ей типичный рельсовый CRUD-контроллер и заприте на админский доступ. В каком ключе вы хотите, чтобы Rails вас понимал?